# Ruby - Timestamp of yesterday to a certain time

Tags: ruby, date, timestamp, operation

I have the following issue:
I want to get the timestamp of yesterday on a specific time.

With what I've come up so far is:

```
Time.local(Time.now.strftime("%Y"), Time.now.strftime("%m"), (Time.now.strftime("%d")-1), 23, 59, 59).tv_sec
```

I'm new to Ruby so that's probably the reason why my Ruby code looks so similar to PHP :)

Maybe it's a help when I say I would like something like this PHP solution in Ruby:

```
mktime(23,59,59,date("m",time()),date("d",time()-86400),date("Y",time()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a problem to use Activesupport?

```
require 'active_support'
Date.yesterday.end_of_day # .to_i to get the timestamp in seconds
#=> Mon Nov 14 23:59:59 +0100 2011
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'
Date.today.to_time - 1  #=> 2011-11-14 23:59:59
```